# Spring Rabbitmq Integration with Multiple Queues

Tags: spring-rabbit

Iam new to Rabbitmq.i want to implement Rabbitmq in my Application to send Emails.for that i need to configure multiple queues then connecting my Email messages to that Queues.for single queue based on Exchange name Application working perfectly but,i tried with multiple queues on that case facing issue while configuring in Spring-context.xml.
Thanks in advance,can any one share sample project of SpringMVC with RabbitMq along multiple queues.
Regards,
Balaji

Comment: Can you explain your problem further? You can simply provide a list of queues to the listener container; edit your question with the configuration, show what you tried and show the error.

Comment: Hi Gary Russell  thanks for your response.i am setting multiple queues in Producer,Consumer are diff Spring MVC Applications.while consuming from one side like Producer application to Consumer application  Listeners in Consumer App working fine.then i am able to produce one message from Consumer App to queue ,while listening from Producer app i have

Comment: It seems like the last sentence is incomplete. Please explain exactly what your issue is and, as I said, edit the question with your configuration.